# Как отсортировать словарь по значениям python по годам

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{'I (W116) 1972-1980': 'I (W116)', 'II (W126) 1979-1985': 'II (W126)', 'II (W126) Рестайлинг 1985-1991': 'II (W126) Рестайлинг', 'III (W140) 1991-1998': 'III (W140)', 'III (W140) Рестайлинг 1994-1999': 'III (W140) Рестайлинг', 'IV (W220) 1998-2005': 'IV (W220)', 'IV (W220) Рестайлинг 2002-2005': 'IV (W220) Рестайлинг', 'V (W221) 2005-2009': 'V (W221)', 'V (W221) Рестайлинг 2009-2013': 'V (W221) Рестайлинг', 'VI (W222, C217) 2013-2017': 'VI (W222, C217)', 'VI (W222, C217) Рестайлинг 2017-2020': 'VI (W222, C217) Рестайлинг', 'VII (W223) 2020-0': 'VII (W223)', 'W108 1965-1972': 'W108', 'W102 2020-0': 'W102'}
```

мне нужно отсортировать этот словарь по годам от старого к новому по значениям как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Если хардкодить, то вот, сортировка на основе года начала.

Важно! захордкожено на символе тире и у года обязательно 4 цифры.

Я бы советовал создать класс у которого есть как минимум два поля дата начала и дата конца, по ним и сортировать, и сделать этот класс ключом словаря

```py
s = {'I (W116) 1972-1980': 'I (W116)', 'II (W126) 1979-1985': 'II (W126)', 'II (W126) Рестайлинг 1985-1991': 'II (W126) Рестайлинг', 'III (W140) 1991-1998': 'III (W140)', 'III (W140) Рестайлинг 1994-1999': 'III (W140) Рестайлинг', 'IV (W220) 1998-2005': 'IV (W220)', 'IV (W220) Рестайлинг 2002-2005': 'IV (W220) Рестайлинг', 'V (W221) 2005-2009': 'V (W221)', 'V (W221) Рестайлинг 2009-2013': 'V (W221) Рестайлинг', 'VI (W222, C217) 2013-2017': 'VI (W222, C217)', 'VI (W222, C217) Рестайлинг 2017-2020': 'VI (W222, C217) Рестайлинг', 'VII (W223) 2020-0': 'VII (W223)', 'W108 1965-1972': 'W108', 'W102 2020-0': 'W102'}

r = sorted(s, key=(lambda k: int(k[k.find('-')-4:k.find('-')])))
print(r)
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помог!